# Unable to write file to external volume using Docker

Tags: python, docker

I have a simple Python program as an example for a Docker image which writes to a file externally.  It doesn't throw any error but it also doesn't write the file on the mounted volume.

Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "/app/test.py"]
```

Here is the Python code:

```python
print("test")
f = open("./demofile2.txt", "a")
f.write("Now the file has more content!")
f.close()
```

Command I used to build the image:

```
sudo docker build --tag=test .
```

Command used for running the image:

```
sudo docker run -ti test -v /home/user:/app
```

Running this setup on Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest Docker version.

The output has no errors. The file seems to be created but I don't know where because the external path doesn't show it.

Comment: Use find command search the file.

Comment: Since the `-v` option is _after_ the image name, it gets passed as the command to run in your image; in your particular setup you should see it in `sys.argv`.  You probably need it _before_ the image name.  You'll also need to store the output file in a different directory from your application code to avoid hiding the script itself with the volume mount.